# Which of the duplicate tags [backtracking], [recursive-backtracking] should be burninated or aliased to the other?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158176/different-behaviors-with-same-time-complexity) on Stack Overflow. It was related to recursive backtracking.

One of the tags I encountered was [recursive-backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-backtracking). Do we really need it? Because I went ahead and tagged it with [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursion), [backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backtracking) and [recursive-backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-backtracking). If I did something incorrect, then how do I distinguish when to use what?

Comment: Would anyone miss it if it was gone? No probably not.  But it's a perfectly valid tag that describes problems that just happen to be covered by other tags.  I don't think you'll find widespread support for removing it.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, I agree with what you say; but just because something works does not necessarily mean that it can be continued.  The `recursive-backtracking` makes searching difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags [backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backtracking), [recursive-backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-backtracking) are duplicates. [All backtracking is recursive backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13782464/202229).

Hence one of these should be removed (burninated/aliased to the other).

Recommendation:

- eliminate [backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backtracking) and keep [recursive-backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-backtracking) since it's less ambiguous
- alias [backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backtracking) -> [recursive-backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-backtracking), rather than burninate, since otherwise it's likely to get created again